# python "shell" not print return value 0 after each successfully executed line

Tags: python, shell, return, interpreter

when i run (for example)

```
print("Hello")
```

the interpreter shows

```
Hello
```

thats perfect, but...

```
from subprocess import call
ls = 'ls'
call(ls)
```

prints

```
file1 file2 file3
0
```

im guessing that the 0 is the return value saying it was successfull (still very new to programming :)   )

soooo..... my question is how to get rid of the 0 so that i only get the output from it, with this example and others as well?

lol im probably over looking something simple here

any help is greatly apreciated!!! :)

EDIT: something like

```
@echo off
```

in windows batch scripts would be prefered(so i can use it once and ignore it)

Comment: You already know about [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Look around the reference, there are many other functions that can be used to execute external commands, and which can capture the output of the command. I recommend a search for `Popen`.

Comment: And if you just don't want the interpreter to output the zero, just assign to a dummy variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2x:
You can use the commands module for getting the output of the command.

```
import commands
commands.getoutput("ls")
```

if you are using python 3x:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput("ls")
```

Comment: after importing getoutput from subprocess i tried                                           ls = ['ls','-I','__init__.py','-I','__pycache__']
getoutput(ls)

Comment: enter the command directly in getoutput as in `getoutput("ls -l init.py")`

Comment: i tried the one for python 3 using 'ls' as a variable for the ls command with arguments(as a string. iv been doing that for subprocess.call())

Comment: the getoutput method accepts a string which is the full command you'd put on the terminal

Comment: getoutput("ls -l __init__.py -I __pycache__") still showed the 0

Comment: ok it worked but i got 'calls.py'. how could i remove the quotes and also run this with 'call()'          (as a command line-like environment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('ls')
# subprocess.check_output('ls', shell=True)
```